# Integrating OpenAI's ChatGPT with Shopify and Interakt Webhook for Improved Customer Support

Tags: node.js, shopify, artificial-intelligence, openai-api

I currently manage a Shopify store and utilize `Interakt` webhook integration with WhatsApp Business for customer support. My Interakt answer bot is set up to provide responses based on predefined FAQs, ensuring efficient handling of customer queries. However, the system falls short when customers make spelling mistakes or use variations in their queries, leading to missed responses.

To address this issue, I aim to enhance the bot's capabilities by integrating `OpenAI's ChatGPT (GPT-3.5 Turbo)` model. The objective is to improve the bot's understanding of customer queries and enable it to respond appropriately, leveraging Shopify customer data.

For example, if a customer types "Track my order" on WhatsApp, the Interakt answer bot should retrieve and respond with the relevant order ID and details from Shopify. However, if there's a spelling mistake such as "Trak order," the current bot fails to respond. I believe integrating ChatGPT could significantly enhance the bot's ability to comprehend and respond effectively to such variations in queries.

I'm seeking guidance on how to proceed with integrating ChatGPT into the existing setup. Specifically, I'd appreciate insights on:

- Setting up the integration between ChatGPT and the Interakt webhook.
- Training ChatGPT to understand and respond to customer queries based on Shopify data.
- Implementing a mechanism to handle misspelled or varied queries effectively.

**References:**

https://apps.shopify.com/whatsapp-chat-api,

https://app.interakt.ai

https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning

Any advice, code snippets, or references to relevant documentation would be highly appreciated. Thank you!